# Using macros in C to assign value t array

Tags: c, multithreading, macros

I have an array : void *functions[n], where n is a constant.

I also have n functions named function1, function2 and so on.

Also, the functions are identical except for the loop values.

1st function  0 -> N/n, 2nd function N/n -> 2*N/n and so on

How can I use macros to simplify this code in C?

EDIT : Since the operations done inside the loop are all independent, I'm dividing the loop into different parts to run multiple threads.

Comment: If the functions are identical except for loop values, is there a good reason they aren't a single function with a parameter which indicates which block of values to operate on? That would also eliminate the need for the function array.

Comment: I'm trying to use multiple threads to run the same code on different parts of the array.

Comment: You don't need a different function for each thread, you just need to set up the thread correctly. You're making life much harder for yourself than it should be.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I'm new to threads.

Comment: Wherever you are invoking functions[x](), instead invoke function(x). You already have 0, 1, 2, etc. that you're using to index into the table. Instead, pass that into the function and use it as your multiplier for the loop values -- ie, go from x*N/n to (x+1)*N/n. Should be almost no change to your calling code, and just one additional parameter for your otherwise-repeated function.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the functions' addresses to array elements and then call the function by invoking through the array

```
fx[0] = function0; // no parenthesis; address of function
fx[1] = function1;
// ...
fx[n-1] = functionn_1;

// ...

// call all functions in a loop
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fx[i]();
}
```

Comment: If “the functions are identical except for the loop values”, then there is nothing that can be achieved with this construction that cannot be achieved with `for(...) function(i);`

Comment: @Emmet: my example code above calls `n` different functions (with no parameters); your example code calls a single function with `n` different parameters.

Comment: I understand that. You answer the question he asked, but without the observation that what he's trying to do makes no sense at all and is achieved *much* better in another way. I think it's worthwhile having that observation as a comment, don't you?